# UTF8 reading Persian string as ? in MySQL 5.0

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I have a table in MySQL 5.0, which I put city names in it in Persian and using a page I try to read a specific city name!
It used to word, but suddenly from today, the city names in my page are all '?????' like!
I go to the phpMyAdmin, change all the collation settings to "utf_persian_ci" and nothing happens!
The interesting part of it is that the "Browse" option of phpMyAdmin shows everything ok (all city names are ok!) but when I try to get them using this kind of query from a page the thing happens:

```
$result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM ".DB_CITIES." WHERE cty_company_id = ".$_GET['cmp']." AND EXISTS (SELECT cu_cmp_id FROM ".DB_COMPANY_USERS." WHERE cu_cmp_id = ".$_GET['cmp']." AND cu_usr_id = $user_id) AND EXISTS (SELECT ctus_user_id FROM scada_city_users WHERE ctus_user_id = $user_id AND ctus_city_id = cty_id)");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to "tell the page" that what you try to read is encoded in UTF8 or whatever encoding you try

Comment: It's not that easy and you need to learn about the topic first. You are looking for encoding (not collation). But start with the MySQL manual first, they have a chapter about encoding. Then go to the W3C website, they have help for encoding and websites as well. When you've done all that, your code will look differently (also you should have learned about SQL injections in between), so update the code and improve the question then if you still have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way to tell the database it should deliver UTF-8 encoded strings. Just tell your connection object, which character-set you expect, the database does the rest for you.

```
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPw, $dbName);

// tell the db to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

The collation only defines how two entries should be compared, it's not the same as defining the charset. Your HTML page shoud also be UTF-8 encoded, some more informations you can find here [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).